# preparedstatement not executing properly

Tags: java, sql

This is my code,

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO customer (c_id, f_name, l_name, address, email, phone)"
                    + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
            prepStmt.setString(1, c_id);
            prepStmt.setString(2, f_name);
            prepStmt.setString(3, l_name);
            prepStmt.setString(4, address);
            prepStmt.setString(5, email);
            prepStmt.setString(6, telephone);
            runUpdateQuery(prepStmt);

            insertSQL = "INSERT INTO reservation (c_id, book_date, s_time, e_time, amount) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
            prepStmt.setString(1, c_id);
            prepStmt.setString(2, date);
            prepStmt.setDouble(3, startTime);
            prepStmt.setDouble(4, endTime);
            prepStmt.setString(5, amount);
            out.println(prepStmt);
            runUpdateQuery(prepStmt);
```

The first statement executes and updates the database, but the second doesnt. I have printed the statement out and ran this directly in psql and the sql code is valid, why wont it work?

Comment: "the second doesn't" really doesn't describe what happens. What are the results? An exception? No exception, but no value? What?

Comment: No exception seems to be thrown, but any code after the execute() method does not run

Comment: Found the problem, date is a date type in sql but string in java, need to cast string to date!

Comment: My guess is that an exception *is* being thrown, but you're swallowing it somewhere. Have you run this in a debugger?

Comment: So presumably an exception *was* being thrown? Before fixing the code, you should fix wherever you're swallowing the exception.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't cast.  You'll have to parse the string and turn it into a data using DateFormat.

Answer (score 1):

An error or log message would help both you and us.

Is there no indication of what's wrong besides the absence of the reservation record?

Schema details might help.  Perhaps you're violating a primary or foreign key constraint.

I'd refactor those into two separate methods and test them individually.

Are these two INSERTs part of a single transaction?  They should be.  What do you want to happen if the reservation INSERT fails?  Should the user roll back?

Your snippet doesn't show how you clean up your resources.  You'd better think about those too, or you'll come to grief later on.

Answer (score 0):

I saw from your own comments that you figured out that the problem was related to JDBC type conversion of dates - glad you resolved it.  This sort of issue comes up quite a bit and it's worth getting well-acquainted with JDBC type conversion.  The following link is a good explanation and reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html

Over the years, I have referred to the tables at the end of the page repeatedly, and so will you.  (I can't find this in the Java 1.7 version of the docs but it should be the same.)